# RabbitMQ subsequent message atomicity

Tags: transactions, rabbitmq, atomic

I have got a RabbitMQ message structure, where a message `A` is supposed to generate a number of messages, let's call them `B` and `C`. A message `A` is received by a worker process, which then processes it and generates messages `B` and `C`.

The supposed workflow process is as follows:

1. Receive a message `A` with `ack=False`
2. Start a transaction
3. Run some code
4. Generate message `B`
5. Generate message `C`
6. Send `ack` for message `A`
7. Complete the transaction

In any case a worker process dies during the processing of message `A`, or while is has not yet completed the transaction - I would like RabbitMQ to treat the message `A` as undelivered and re-queue it.

RabbitMQ runs in highly available configuration if that is relevant.

Why question is trying to clear the RabbitMQ documentation [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html), stating:

> Furthermore, RabbitMQ provides no atomicity guarantees even in case of transactions involving just a single queue, e.g. a fault during tx.commit can result in a sub-set of the transaction's publishes appearing in the queue after a broker restart.

- Is there any way I could achieve the behaviour I would like in the context of RabbitMQ or any other queueing software on the market?
- Is there any way I could make that work for multiple queues with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake by targeting the most popular product, as it seemed to me. ActiveMQ has full support for high-availability and transactions, so I have just switched to that and my problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need quite a bit of infrastructure (code) to get this working just right.  It is rather tricky.

You may want to consider a service bus.  I have a free .net open-source one here: http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/

If you are not in the .net space or are not interested in using a service bus you could follow some of the code to see how some of these things have been handled by Shuttle.Esb: https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb

You may also want to take a look at the `IdempotenceService` here: https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb.SqlServer/blob/master/Shuttle.ESB.SqlServer/Idempotence/IdempotenceService.cs

When using the idempotence server (in a handler) all sent message are stored in a transaction store (like sql server in this case) and are only sent after the message handling has completed successfully.

For sending outside of a message handler one could use a transactional outbox (again, a sql server table-based queue would work).

The point is that you need to give your design some serious thought and it is going to be tricky.

Comment: I know exactly how to implement this - an SQL-backed solution would be a naïve solution to that.

My issue is finding the right software that would be able to do that efficiently at RabbitMQ performance level, rather than Postgres/MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

We've got a few systems that work exactly like this in production, with that basic format of:

1. Get message A
2. Do work
3. Acknowledge message A

Where if step #2 fails, message A is "re-queued" and available to be picked up again.

When a message is sent to a queue and successfully received, that message is marked as `ready`. When it's then sent to a consumer it's marked as `unacked` until acknowledged by said consumer at which point it's removed from the queue.

In your example, until you've acknowledged the message in step #6 it's still in the `unacked` state, meaning if the worker process died before step #6 the message would slide back to the `ready` state in *RabbitMQ*, ready to be sent to another worker.

This functionality does rely on the fact that you're not explicitly disabling acknowledgements. If you were, I'm pretty sure messages are immediately removed from the queue upon being sent to a consumer.

Comment: What if you're expected to send a subsequent message B after message A? Obviously, in an atomic manner - "ack and publish message B" or "noack and message B has never been published"?

Comment: In that case, you'd send message B during the "_Do work_" stage, so if message A then gets acked you know that message B has been sent and vice versa.

Comment: What if the message could be sent, but the work could not be done?

Comment: Then that's more down to how you send and handle messages.

Personally when using message queues I make sure that the consumers I write do only a single job, so if a message has been handled then I know _all_ of the work has been completed.

So in your case if you wanted to both send message B _and_ do some work, make two _different_ consumers, one that will send messages and one that will do work.

Regardless of the queuing system used, performing multi-stage tasks is risky which is why [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) is such an important factor too.